# Laravel's with method returns null

Tags: php, laravel, orm

laravel Eloquent with() method, $this->model::find($no)->holder can can see the results.but with method always null

```
  public function holder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Holder', 'holder_no', 'no');
    }


public function bankAccount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\BankAccount', 'holder_no', 'no');
    }



public function getBankCardDetail(array $params): array
{
    $card_detail = $this->model::with('holder:no,name')
        ->select([
            'holder_no'
        ])
        ->where([
            'no'=>$params['no']
        ])
        ->first()
        ->toArray();

    return $card_detail;
}


   "data": {
        "holder_no": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "holder": null
    }


select `holder_no` from `bank_accounts` where (`no` = 'CGRWVF93HAOYHXZSCR4KVZ') limit 1  
select `no`, `name` from `holders` where `holders`.`no` in (0)
```

I don't know where the problem is. laravel 5.8

Comment: Is `getBankCardDetail()` a method on the model?

Comment: and what is `$this->model`?

Comment: Have you tried adding the primary key field in field list? Please add `id` field and find out if that solves the problem.

Comment: getBankCardDetail() is a method on the model, $this->model is the same function as App\model .

Answer (score 0):

the no and the name shall be included in the select either way it won't works.

Comment: Problem solved ，add "$keyType = 'string'" in the model,  The default keyType in laravel's ORM is int, but mine is string.